# How to getValues() with Google Script from Sheets so the date values matches

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script

I have a range of cells which contain dates in the following format:

7/27/2018 17:03:46

When I use:

```
var range = spreadsheet.getRange(1, 1, 20).getValues();  
Logger.log(range[1][0]);
```

I get

> Sat Jul 28 02:03:46 GMT+02:00 2018

instead of

> 7/27/2018 17:03:46

How do I get the correct value?

My Timezone is GMT +02:00

I've tried using new Date().

The link below will take you to the Spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H7MAEfr0QbFuNwA8N_bm-08f_Phs8G2NNOQDYG-IA4E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: How about using ``getDisplayValues()`` instead of ``getValues()`` like ``var range = spreadsheet.getRange(1, 1, 20).getDisplayValues();``? By this, the displayed values can be retrieved. The document is [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues). If this was not useful for your situation, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved

The problem was the origin of the data. I was copying and pasting the table values from an Excel Spreadsheet which is a log from a Chinese machine which as a different time zone. When I copied and paste from Excel to Google Sheets it changes the timezone of Google Sheets :l